# How change Google Analytics account in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-analytics-firebase

As you can see on the screenshot below, I already tested the Google Analytics with my private Google Analytics account for my private apps.

```
File --> Project Structure .. -> Developer Service --> Analytics
```

[image: screenshot]

Now, I would like to go play around with my business apps as well and would like to enter my corporate email Google Analytics account, which is combined to that other app. **How can I switch or logout here?**

Comment: In case below answer doesnt work you can try my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36542365/5505915)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove the Analytics library dependency `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'` from your build.gradle. (manually, not from module settings)
2. To avoid errors comment out Analytics related code.
3. Do a gradle sync.
4. Clean and build your project.
   [*4.1. Just to be safe Do an invalidate cache and restart from file menu.*]
5. Go back to module settings and enable Analytics. (It should now ask for a login again.)
6. Login with your new user
7. Uncomment the code that you commented earlier.