# How to clear/reset Google Analytic credentials from Android Studio?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I was performing Google Analytic using Android Studio. I successfully create an sample application.

Now I want to use another gmail in Google Analytic, but there is no option of logout in Analytic's dialog.

Here I a snapshot,

[image]

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34905221/5505915) but it is not working in my case.

Please help me to reset analytic account in Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found answer my self. There is a icon on right top side. Here is a snap of it.

[image]

I clicked on it and it allowed me to add new google account in it.

[image]

I added new account and my issue is resolved.